# How to precisely count words in my text?

Tags: count

Is there an official way to count words in a text? If so, is there an official website?

I need to write something EXACTLY a thousand words long, but every website I try gives me a different result...

Thank you!

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It is about (a) essay length calculation and (b) resources, not meaning and syntax etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Do you know which forum I should turn to then?

Comment: This is English.  There is no such thing as an official anything.

Comment: I'd say you need to contact your regulating body. Their way of counting say open and/or hyphenated compounds, punctuation marks etc may differ from those of the institution just five miles away. There may be many 'official' ways. But doubtless no universally agreed way.

Comment: There is no standard word count method because there is no standard definition for "word" in English. Words can be optionally hyphenated, or optionally contracted, with or without spelling differences. How you gonna count _gonna_, for instance? Or _sweat shirt_?

Comment: I think the essence of this question is *what is a word* within the context of word processing. I think that’s interesting and not off topic.

Comment: This might help (it automatically counts the words for you): https://wordcounter.net/

Comment: Typists define "word" (for the purpose of WPM ratings) as (I forget exactly) something like 6 characters (including blanks and punctuation).

Comment: Thank you all! I think I will go with Microsoft word counter then :)
Just to be more precise, I do not have a "regulating body", it is for a short story I am writing where I need someone to speak exactly a hundred words :)
So I don't have anybody in authority to refer to...

Anyway, thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but here is a [Wikipedia snippet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_count) on **word count** which is largely focused on the **strict definition of a word** within the context of word processing.

> Variations in the operational definitions of how to count the words can occur (namely, what "counts as" a word, and which words "don't count" toward the total). However, especially since the advent of widespread word processing, there is a broad consensus on these operational definitions (and hence the bottom-line integer result). The consensus is to accept the text segmentation rules generally found in most word processing software (including how word boundaries are determined, which depends on how word dividers are defined). The first trait of that definition is that a space (any of various whitespace characters, such as a "regular" word space, an em space, or a tab character) is a word divider. Usually a hyphen or a slash is, too. Different word counting programs may give varying results, depending on the text segmentation rule details, and on whether words outside the main text (such as footnotes, endnotes, or hidden text) are counted. But the behavior of most major word processing applications is broadly similar.

Whilst different tools may give different counts, when one [reads](https://m.windowscentral.com/there-are-now-12-billion-office-users-60-million-office-365-commercial-customers) that :

> Microsoft offered some updates on its Office products during its Build 2016 day 2 keynote. Microsoft says there are now 1.2 billion users worldwide that use some kind of Office product or service.

then Microsoft Word is pretty much a *de facto* standard for anything word processing related, including word counts.

Answer (score 1):

From a linguistic perspective, there are three ways to define a word: phonologically, morphologically, and syntactically. Word counts, and word boundaries will be mostly similar across the different definitions, but will not always coincide. Therefore, there can be no single definition of word. This is the argument advanced in a recent volume by [Dixon and Aikhenvald](https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/32571998/Word_a_Cross-linguistic_Typology.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1525401615&Signature=LsKNVKOVqTBZISONNLHoMFcLcmM%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D32571998.pdf#page=17). So under this view, even with a computer program that understands language as well as a human, there cannot be consensus on the "word" count.

Now when it comes to a written text, there are still some choices that have to be made even if you say that a word is everything bounded by whitespace. Do you count numerals? Captions and titles? What about nonce hyphenated words, or multi-word foreign expressions (*je ne sais quoi*)? What about typos where two words accidentally run together? The computer can get a better count the more you try to make it parse the text. See some other orthography-based issues in the comments to the OP's question.

Then finally, artifacts of the computer encoding. If you paste something to the textarea that has unprintable characters or characters from a different encoding, how is it going to handle those?

These, and basic human error, are going to be some reasons why you get different counts.